# Несколько слайдеров на одной странице

Tags: slider

Стоит задача создать несколько слайдеров скажем 5 штук, и надо чтобы картинки менялись по очереди, например первый слайдер поменял картинку через 5 секунд, остальные стоят, потом другой слайдер через 5 секунд и остальные тоже стоят, можно было бы еще при каждой загрузке, рандомно выбирался слайдер для начала смены картинки, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У нормальных плагинов слайд шоу есть функция отвечающая за:

- начальный и или текущий слайд;
- отключение автоплей;
- ручное (скриптовое) пролистывание.

Пишется скрипт который поочерёдно с временным интервалом обращается к каждому слайдеру и выполняет листание.

---

Автор ответа: IT-студия modXart.com